# Get an element when using ng-if is undefined. Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

All the default elements are hidden.

```
$scope.hide=false;
ng-if="hide"
```

I want it when I click on a link, it shows the corresponding element. But I do not know how to show only the element that corresponds. For example if I click on

```
<li> <a href=''ng-click="show('section1')"> section1 </a> </ li>
```

The element with the 'section1' id must be displayed. After that, I do not know why the element is not found.

```
Var myEl = angular.element (document.querySelector ('#' + id));
```

Do this using the ng-if statement.

http://jsfiddle.net/8jmnpn2u/

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

http://jsfiddle.net/8jmnpn2u/2/

Simply you can do it by $scope variable

Define  `$scope.currentDiv = "";`

and on show function just update  `$scope.currentDiv`

Your HTML code

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='' ng-click="show('section1')">section1</a></li>
    <li><a href='' ng-click="show('section2')">section2</a></li>
    <li><a href='' ng-click="show('section3')">section3</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
   <section id='section1' ng-if="currentDiv == 'section1'"> 
   1
  </section>
   <section id='section2' ng-if="currentDiv == 'section2'"> 
   2
  </section>
   <section id='section3' ng-if="currentDiv == 'section3'"> 
   3
  </section>
</body>
```

Angular controller

```
// the main (app) module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.swiper']);

// add a controller
myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.msg = "hello world";
  $scope.currentDiv = "";
    $scope.show= function(id){
    $scope.currentDiv = id;
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks good, but I need to get the element with . angular.element (document.querySelector ('#' + id));

Comment: @yavg Please explain in detail. if you will updated hide = true / false it will affect all div(s) . you need to compare with (==) or define different variables . always try to prefer native methods.

Comment: I need to get the html element. I do this with this (document.querySelector ('#' + id)); But I get nothing. I need to calculate this to the id I get. do you understand me?

Comment: Please, look at the link you uploaded. My idea was to get the html element also in the controller. Line 14

Comment: @yavg try 
 var myEl = angular.element(document.getElementById(id));

Answer (score 0):

Try this: if you create an array to keep the 'hide' value of yor sections, you can control them independently

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='' ng-click="show('section1')">section1</a></li>
    <li><a href='' ng-click="show('section2')">section2</a></li>
    <li><a href='' ng-click="show('section3')">section3</a></li>

  </ul>
</nav>
   <section id='section1' ng-if="hide['section1']"> 
   1
  </section>
   <section id='section2' ng-if="hide['section2']"> 
   2
  </section>
   <section id='section3' ng-if="hide['section3']"> 
   3
  </section>
</body>
```

the main (app) module

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.swiper']);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.hide = [];

  $scope.show= function(id){
    $scope.hide[id] = true;
    var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#'+id ));
  }
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2c71bjuu/